# Quiero hacer que los menus esten pegados a logo

Tags: html, css

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li style="float:left;">logo</li>
    <li><a href="">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu3</a></li>
  </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Preguntas y respuestas que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor revisa [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu ul li {
  float: left; /*Atiende esta linea porque la tenias al revés*/
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Preguntas y respuestas que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor revisa [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)